# Run CustomTool PublicResXFileCodeGenerator outside Visual Studio

Tags: c#, resx, resgen

I have a resx file that only contains strings.  When I edit this file in VS2022, the `Resources.Designer.cs` file is updated to match the resx file contents.

I have a tool that updates the resx (xml file) and I would like the designer file to match.  I believe the designer file is created/updated by running the associated custom tool.  In this case, the custom tool is `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`.

I can use `resgen.exe` to create the designer file, and this works OK, but the tool version for `resgen` is 4.0.0.0, whereas, if I generate the file from VS2022, the tool version is 17.0.0.0.

How can I run the custom tool used by Visual Studio, but without loading Visual Studio and manually running the tool?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732926/how-can-i-find-the-latest-visual-studio-developer-command-prompt-in-a-batch-file